# WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0 & API Manager 2.1.0 same ports?

Tags: https, wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Currently I configure WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0 and API Manager 2.1.0 in one same server. For Identity server 5.3.0 run as "9443" and API Manager run as "9444" ports.

Is there any way to make both of this WSO2 products using "HTTPS" which is run in same "443" ports?

http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/11/16/how-to-developing-identity-server-behind-proxy-or-load-balancer/

I have already try to config the proxy based on this link and also other WSO2 documentation and it unsuccessful.

If can, is there any proper configuration guide on how to config?

Kindly required a guidline.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer [WSO2 Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+Nginx) for this.

Comment: Thank you  for your answer, but currently i am using Windows Server to run both of this product.
I already try this method based on your answer. NGINX is used in Linux right?